# How to check in and/or discard check out all pending shared documents?

Tags: check-out, check-in

Currently in my team, we share Word .docx files via `Shared Documents` of Sharepoint page.

The issue we have now is that if someone check out many files, we have to ask him/her to release it. This is quite an inconvenience working!

How can I check in and/or discard check out all pending shared files? We currently have to do that one by one.

ps.

I found one guide here from Microsoft but with that, I have to go site by site to discard the checked out files - I need a list of all checked out ones.

Comment: If the user has checked-out a file and made any kind of modifications, if you take over his file either by checking-in or discarding his check-out he will lose the content.

Comment: I mean files of mine - the ones I checked out myself

Answer (score 3):

Go to the Document library. Select Library tab from the ribbon. Check if individual checkboxes are present in each row. If not, click on Modify View in the ribbon and check "Allow individual item checkboxes" in Tabular View section and click on OK. Now Select the check box next to the file icon for each file you want to check in, check out, or discard. Select Files tab and click on either check in, check out, or discard depending on the requirement. Note that user must have permission level

> Override List Behaviors  -  Discard or check in a document which is
>   checked out to another user, and change or override settings which
>   allow users to read/edit only their own items

This permission is available to users with "Full Control" permission level.

Answer (score 3):

To check in all files checked out to you, or not yet checked in (happens when uploading folders from Windows Explorer):

- Document / Library (top ribbon)
- Create View / Standard View
- - Name: CheckedOutToMe
- - Audience: Create a Public View
- - Filter: Checked Out To / is equal to / [Me]
- - Tabular View: Allow indivdual item checkboxes
- - Folders: Folders or Flat = Show all items without folders
- - Item Limit: 100 (max numbers of items selectable together to do a check in)
- - OK
- Document / Library (top ribbon)
- Current view: CheckedOutToMe
- Files (top ribbon)
- select all (first 100 items), Check In (top ribbon)
- iterate the selectAll/checkIn for all group of 100 files you need to check in

Comment: Thanks - I wasted time looking for a working PS script. In the end, your approach was faster.

Comment: Or so it seemed. In the end your approach did not help, because SPO enforces the 5000 list item limit and will not show more, even when filtered, in a flat list. So I never got to check in half of my 10,000 documents. In the end, I turned off "Require documents to be checked out before they can be edited" in the site's versioning settings (site settings > site libraries and lists > customize documents) and redid my migration with spFileZilla. The documents were no longer checked out.