# Check in multiple documents at once

Tags: check-in

One of our users did a bulk drag and drop of many files while we had version control turned on.  Now they are all checked out.  Is there a way to check them all in at once?  We don't need any comments on these documents.

Comment: Can you clarify which version of SharePoint this is for? E.g., SharePoint 2007, 2010, 2013?

Answer (score 3):

You can do so by selecing all documents (clicking on the left of each one), then from the ribbon in the "Files" tab, click "check in".

Answer (score 0):

There are some solutions in this other question: [How do I check in a LOT of files all at once?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/12214/how-do-i-check-in-a-lot-of-files-all-at-once)

You have options:

- User interface
- Powr Shell
- SharePoint Designer
- Other Tools

Hope it will be helpfull

Comment: I probably should have mentioned there were many folders and sub-folders.  When I click on the Folders the "Check-in" is greyed out. 
I ended up taking ownership and then selecting all files in each folder and checking them in.