# How can I check-in multiple files at once SharePoint 2013?

Tags: 2013, check-in

I've been doing a lot of reading and research today, but haven't been able to find a solution that works for me.

Up until yesterday, our sales team was able to mass-check out files for tracking, fill in the data on each file that they needed and then mass check the files back in while adding a check-in comment that would apply to all the files being checked-in. This is how we constructed our document workflow to advance.

It seems with the Windows Update last night, we no longer have the ability to do this and files have to be checked back in individually, as you can imagine this creates a lot more work on our sales team.

Our IT budget is limited so I am unable to purchase a web part for this, does anyone have any ideas or suggestions? It's frustrating because it was working fine yesterday.

*edit/update* after setting up a test subsite with only 4 documents I am still able to check those in simultaneously as before, it seems to be a quantity of items in the list, under setting I'm showing 4045 items with a threshold of 5000. I don't know if this helps anyone figure out the issue. I read through the changelog of the sharepoint updates yesterday and I don't see anything that could've impacted this but something definitely changed making our reps unable to check-in multiple files.

Thanks,

Answer (score 7):

There are many different ways of doing this.

The simplest it is use SharePoint Designer. 
Please open your site in SharePoint Designer, navigate to "All Files" and select your Document Library. On the ribbon click "Check-In" and OK

[image]

Answer (score 4):

When you have several things checked out and you want to check them in all at once, select the “My Checked Out Items” (Instead of “All Documents”) view. This will show you which items are checked out to you.

Click on the first document you want to check in (it becomes highlighted), then hit “Shift” and click on the other documents you want to check in, one at a time. When they are all highlighted, look at the top of your window, where you will see the options “Browse-Files-Library.” Click on “Files.”

In the ribbon at the top, you will see several categories of options. The second one is “Open & Check Out.” Under that category, you’ll see “Check Out,” “Check In” and “Discard Check Out.” Hit “Check In.” This will (obviously) check in all of the documents that you have selected.

Conversely, you can also select multiple documents and use the “Check Out” button under the same “Files” window to check several items out all at once rather than doing it individually, which is a pain.

Comment: Best answer for those of us who don't have Sharepoint Designer installed!  I had to create a new view for My Checked Out Items, though -- it wasn't present in my library.  Just filtered for Checked Out To = [Me] and flattened the folder structure (in case someone else wants to know how).

Answer (score 1):

Go to site actions -> Manage content and structure. At the first page there is a list of the files with a "view" in the toolbar on the right section. Drop this down and choose "`Checked out to me`".

This will list all the files, you can then check the check box to select all items and in the actions drop down choose check in.

Comment: I don't find any options for Site Actions, I googled it and it looks like it was replaced in the SharePoint 2013 with the setting gear button. Under that there are no manage content and structure options. There is a site contents option but don't see anything similar to what you are describing.

Comment: Can you check for this option "Content and Structure logs" under Site Settings->Site Administration?

Comment: Under site administration, I only show Regional Settings, Language Setting, Site libraries and lists, user alerts, rss, sites and workspaces, workflow seeting, site closure and deletion, term store management, popularity trends, and translation status.

Comment: Is your site a publishing site?

Comment: Also, What edition of SharePoint server is installed? Is it foundation?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure, the guy who set it up is no longer with the company and I've been tasked with trying to figure this problem out with little inherent knowledge.

Comment: I think we're Sharepoint Online? would be my guess, I believe it's hosted by Microsoft. I have the SharePoint 2013 Web Designer.

Answer (score 0):

I've been experiencing the same issues I'm trying to check in 100 documents in one hit but for some reason it does not want to do a bulk check in anymore.

I have noted a unusual anomaly, if I tick each one individually occasionally one will not show a check in on the quick bar (files/open & Check out) if I tick each one that the check in icon appears I am able to bulk check in again.

We have only noticed this within the last month or so also.

SharePoint designer of coarse works fine....

I'm hoping it's a glitch that will be fixed soon.

Answer (score 0):

I am migrating our company documents onto Office365 Sharepoint Online and required to check in multiple documents (in fact, an entire library at once).

Credit to the author of [this script](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Find-all-checked-out-files-56fd562d) (Arleta Wanat) which I modified to check in multiple files.