# How to publish all files in SharePoint document library

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, office-365

How to publish all items in a document library instead of going file by file and publish.

Comment: Check this: http://www.rapidcircle.com/powershell-publishing-all-files-in-a-sharepoint-online-library/ and this: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/publishing-all-items-in-document-library-using-powershell-script1

Comment: If you are looking for SharePoint on-prem, maybe this will help: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/12214/how-do-i-check-in-a-lot-of-files-all-at-once